# Web.config builder section prefixes don't match App Service behavior

Tags: azure, configuration, paas

The stock web.config contains this entry:

```
 <configBuilders>
    <builders>
      <add name="SitecoreAppSettingsBuilder" mode="Strict" prefix="SITECORE_APPSETTINGS_" stripPrefix="true"
        type="Sitecore.Configuration.FlexibleEnvironmentConfigBuilder, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
      <add name="SitecoreConnectionStringsBuilder" mode="Strict" prefix="SITECORE_CONNECTIONSTRINGS_" stripPrefix="true"
        type="Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.EnvironmentConfigBuilder, Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Environment, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral"/>
    </builders>
  </configBuilders>
```

However, if you add a connection string to an app service configuration setting, as documented [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/101/platform-administration-and-architecture/protect-the-connection-string-passwords-from-unauthorized-access.html#encrypt-the-connectionstrings-config-file-in-an-azure-paas-app-service-environment), the connection strings will in fact be prefixed with a value like `SQLCONNSTR_` or `SQLAZURECONNSTR_`, depending on a user selection when entering the value. This is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common?tabs=portal#configure-connection-strings).  Is there a reason why SItecore ships with the non-standard value in Web.config, and is there an approved or standard way of setting this in Azure?

I'm inclined to simply update the `<builders>` prefix value, but curious if there are other standard approaches here.

Comment: I think the reason was to provide a platform agnostic configuration builder, that would work for all platforms that support environment variables, and not just for Azure PaaS. With Azure PaaS app services though, I usually like to rely on the native Azure App Services capabilities and use the connection strings names without prefix for their respective settings keys (ie. "master", "web",...).

Comment: Don't they get prefixed then with the connection string type? E.g. SQLCONNSTR_master.  (See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common?tabs=portal#configure-connection-strings).  I was thinking I could put "SQLCONNSTR_" in the config builder prefix setting, but that means you need to use that option for things like Solr URLs, which feels a little hackly.

Comment: I think this old article explains the extra runtime "magic" that allows the mapping from environment variables to connection strings configuration in ASP.NET applications: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/windows-azure-web-sites-how-application-strings-and-connection-strings-work/

Answer (score 0):

As [Alessandro Faniuolo](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/users/1399/alessandro-faniuolo) points out, ASP.NET sites have another mechanism in addition to environment variables to access these settings, so the prefix in Web.config does not need to match what PaaS generates.

Adding a connection string for, say, "web", in the "Configuration" blade "Connection Strings" section will cause it to get mapped by the ConfigurationManager to the "web" database connection string.

See the [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/windows-azure-web-sites-how-application-strings-and-connection-strings-work/) he links to above for an explanation of how this works:

> For ASP.NET web applications, there is some extra runtime magic that is available as well when using the .NET 4.5 framework.

This "magic" bypasses the environment variables.